# How to run a Fargate Task on an existing ecs cluster using aws cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have an ECS cluster that will be created by my cdk stack. Before my ECS service stack deployment I have to run a fargate task to generate the build files and configs for my application. I want to run a standalone task inside an existing Ecs cluster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two questions. I Will try to answer both:

1. First of all you need to run the Fargate task via CDK

you need to create a Rule which runs your ECS task by schedule (or some else event)

> ```
> import { Rule, Schedule } from '@aws-cdk/aws-events';
> import { EcsTask } from '@aws-cdk/aws-events-targets';
>
> new Rule(this, 'ScheduleRule', {
>         schedule: schedule,
>         targets: [
>           new EcsTask({
>             cluster,
>             taskDefinition: task,
>           }),
>         ],
>       });
> ```

2. Second one - how I can use the existing cluster

you can find your cluster by attributes

> ```
> import { Cluster } from '@aws-cdk/aws-ecs';
>
> let cluster = Cluster.fromClusterAttributes(this, 'cluster_id', {
>      clusterName: "CLUSTER_NAME", securityGroups: [], vpc: iVpc
>  });
> ```

**update**:
you can trigger your task via some custom event:

> ```
>  new Rule(this, 'EventPatternRule', {
>          eventPattern: {
>              "version": "0",
>              "id": "CWE-event-id",
>              "detail-type": "CodePipeline Pipeline Execution State Change",
>              "source": "aws.codepipeline",
>              "account": "123456789012",
>              "time": "2017-04-22T03:31:47Z",
>              "region": "us-east-1",
>              "resources": [
>                  "arn:aws:codepipeline:us-east-1:123456789012:pipeline:myPipeline"
>              ],
>              "detail": {
>                  "pipeline": "myPipeline",
>                  "version": "1",
>                  "state": "STARTED",
>                  "execution-id": "01234567-0123-0123-0123-012345678901"
>              }
>          }
>          targets: [
>            new EcsTask({
>              cluster,
>              taskDefinition: task,
>            }),
>          ],
>        });
> ```

please, see [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatchEventsandEventPatterns.html) for the understanding of Event Patterns

Comment: Thank you so much, if possible can you share with me an example of how to trigger based on an event